# Is gathering namespace functions into a map via a macros idiomatic Clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm learning Clojure via a pet project. The project would consist of several *workers* that would be called from other functions.

Each worker is defined in their own namespace as a set of functions (currently two: `get-data` for gathering data and `write-data` for writing the gathered data into a file).

In order to make the code a bit DRYer, I decided to write a macro that would gather functions from namespace into a map that can be passed around:

```
(ns clojure-bgproc.workers)

(defmacro gen-worker-info []
  (let [get-data (ns-resolve *ns* 'get-data)
        write-data (ns-resolve *ns* 'write-data)]
    `(def ~(quote worker-info)
       {:get-data ~get-data
        :write-data ~write-data}
       )
    )
  )
```

In my worker code, I use my macro (code abridged for clarity):

```
(ns clojure-bgproc.workers.summary
  (:require [clojure-bgproc.workers :refer [gen-worker-info]]))

(defn get-data [params]
  <...>
  )

(defn write-data [data file]
  ;; <...>
  )

(gen-worker-info)
```

While it does work (I get my `get-data` and `write-data` functions in `clojure-bgproc.workers.summary/worker-info`, I find it a bit icky, especially since, if I move the macro call to the top of the file, it doesn't work.

My question is, is there a more idiomatic way to do so? Is this idiomatic Clojure at all?

Thank you.

Comment: this may be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ohh, okay, thank you! Is it okay to crosspost it there? Or should I delete this question here first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're in a weird spot because you've structured your program wrong:

> Each worker is defined in their own namespace as a set of functions

This is the real problem. Namespaces are a good place to put functions and values that you will refer to in hand-written code. For stuff you want to access programmatically, they are not a good storage space. Instead, make the data you want to access first-class by putting it into an ordinary proper data structure, and then it's easy to manipulate.

For example, this `worker-info` map you're thinking of deriving from the namespace is great! In fact, that should be the *only* way workers are represented: as a map with keys for the worker's functions. Then you just define somewhere a list (or vector, or map) of such worker maps, and that's your list of workers. No messing about with namespaces needed.

Answer (score 3):

My go-to solution for defining the workers would be *Protocols*. I would also apply some of the well-tried frameworks for system lifecycle management.

[Protocols](https://clojure.org/reference/protocols) provide a way of defining a set of methods and their signatures. You may think of them as similar, but more flexible than, *interfaces* in object-oriented programming.

Your workers will probably have some state and life-cycle, e.g., the workers may be running or stopped, acquiring and releasing a resource, and so on. I suggest you take a look at [Integrant](https://github.com/weavejester/integrant) for managing a system with stateful components (i.e., workers).

I would argue for avoiding macros in this case. The adage [*data over functions over macros*](https://lispcast.com/data-functions-macros-why/) seems to apply here. Macros are not available at runtime, make debugging harder, and force all other programmers who look at your code to learn a new Domain-Specific Language, i.e., the one you defined with your macros.